# Microsoft Graph API, cant retrieve profile picture with django

Tags: python, django, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having the issue that requesting the photo from the Microsoft Graph API does not retrieve the photo and actually returns a 404 error.

`xff/xd8/xff/xe0/x00/x10JFIF/x00/x01/x01/x01/x00%60/x00%60/x00/x00/xff/xdb/x00C/x00/x08/x06/x06/x07/x06/x05/x08/x07/x07/x07/t/t/x08/n/x0c/x14/r/x0c/x0b/x0b/x0c/x19/x12/x13/x0f/x14/x1d/x1a/x1f/x1e/x1d/x1a/x1c/x1c%20$./'%20%22,`

i get this is the base64 decoded jpeg, however i cant figure out how to use it to actually display an image in a html page.

Here is the code in my views that is creating the request, which is in my initialize context view:

```
def initialize_context(request):
## non relevant code ##

        graph_photo_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value'
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
        photo_response = requests.get(graph_photo_endpoint, headers=headers)
        if photo_response.status_code == 200:
            context['photo_data'] = photo_response.content
            photo_response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'

## non relevant code ##
    return context
```

Which is retrieved by my view that needs to load the photo, which the user needs to be signed in for to access:

```
@azure_ad_login_required
def profile(request):
    context = initialize_context(request)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Here is the html code to define the photo:

```
<img class="profile_pic" src="{{ photo_data }}" alt="Profile Picture" style="width:100%">
```

And this is what my graph_helper looks like:

```
import requests
import base64
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'

def get_user(token):
    # Send GET request to retrieve user information from Microsoft Graph API
    user = requests.get('{0}/me'.format(graph_url),
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)},
                        params={'$select': 'displayName,mail,mailboxSettings,userPrincipalName,givenName,companyName,surName,jobTitle'})
    user.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    return user.json()
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here, anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input, this made me think about why i would do it the way i was doing it.
This made me come up with this solution:

```
token = get_token(request)
context = initialize_context(request)
graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'
photo_endpoint = f"{graph_url}/me/photo/$value"
access_token = token

response = requests.get(photo_endpoint, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}, stream=True)

if response.ok:
    # Save the photo locally or process it as needed
    with open('static/assets/main/images/profile_photo.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(chunk)
else:
    # Handle error if photo retrieval fails
    print(f"Failed to retrieve profile photo: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

and for the html side:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/main/images/profile_photo.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" style="width:100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the line

```
context['photo_data'] = photo_response.content
```

in `initialize_context`, and try amending that line to:

```
context['photo_data'] = io.BytesIO(photo_response.content)
```

You'll need to import IO at the top of that file:

```
import io
```

I typically [create an abstract user class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and create a one to one UserProfile class to saving/cache the image. Using Django's [ImageFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#the-imagefile-class) in a manner similar to:

```
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
...    

profile_photo = io.BytesIO(photo_response.content)
# userprofile being the instance of userprofile previously set
userprofile.avatar = ImageFile(profile_photo, name='foo.jpg')
```

Then in a template file I can use:

```
<img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="{{ request.user.userprofile.avatar.url }}" alt="Image of {{ request.user.displayname }}">
```

If you are not storing the image, you may need to embed the base64 encoding right in the src, however, I don't like doing that as for each request, you need to go look up the image (which I think is unnecessary).

You may end up with something like what is described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html/) at :

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ photo_data }}" />
```

but I'm not sure if you'd have the b64 data in `photo_data` context or not. You may need to test that out.

No guarantee any of that will work - I've got a very different sort of setup than you in how I retrieve those images but maybe there is something here that will help you out.